# c++ VS-2019 Linker errror trying to link standalone class implementation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, linker-errors

I am working in C++ using VS-19 and having some linker issues I do not understand. I am coming from Java so I am not deep on building and linking plus I am working with kind of "legacy" code here so there might be things I don't grasp at all. I am getting this same error with multiple functions and classes but I am describing only one example here.

So I have a main function which calls the **checkConnection** function from the same file. Which in turn is referencing a class (myIp) defined in a different file which is in a different folder. When trying to call a function on the myIp object I get a linker error:

*error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall myIp::Connect(class AnsiString,int,unsigned int)" (?Connect@TIP@@QAEHVAnsiString@@HII_N@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl checkConnection(void)" (?checkConnection@@YAHXZ)*

**Folder Structure:**

My main File: **..\projects\c++\ATT\MyApp--> here is all the stuff VS created when I started my new Solution**

The myip File to include: **..\projects\c++\utilities--> here is the myIp.h and myIp.cpp files**

This is what I have in my **VS\Project Properties\VC++ Directories\Include Directories: ..\projects\c++\utilities**

The myIp files are not part of a project or solution bound to VS just standalone class implementation.

**This is my main code:**

```cpp
#include <myIp.h>

int checkConnection(AnsiString host, int url_port)
{
   myIp conn;

   if (conn.Connect(host, url_port, 10000))
   {
     // do magic
   }
   
   return 0;
}

int main()
{
   AnsiString host = "http://10.20.30.40";
   int port = 80;
   return checkConnection(host, port);
}
```

**This is the function declaration in myIp.h:**

```
#ifndef classMYIPH
#define classMYIPH

class myIp
{

   public:
      myIp();
      ~myIp();
      int Connect(AnsiString ipadr, int port, unsigned int 
               timeoutms=4000, unsigned int tries=1, bool event = false);

};
```

**This is the function I am calling in myIp.cpp:**

```
int myIp::Connect(AnsiString host, int port, unsigned int timeoutms, unsigned int tries, bool event)
{
   // do connect
   // if connection successfull return 1 else 0
}
```

Comment: ***defined in a different file which is in a different folder*** The folder does not matter. Are the files that implement the myIp class part of the project?

Comment: @drescherjm No these are standalone class implementations which I want to use in my project. They are listed in the "External Dependencies" tab in my VS solution though (if that matters)

Comment: I believe they need to be part of the project or in a library or the object files need to be linked. I have not heard of a "standalone class implementations" in c++.

Answer (score 0):

`myIp(); ~myIp();` lack definitions and you need to complete code or comment them.